# How to obtain vector from iteration result of for loop in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, iteration

I have this data frame (df) and I need to get a vector of the values in the column "amountN" when the "ID" column matches the values of a given vector (idvector), so I've created a for loop that I tested by printing the values of df$amountN to check they actually are accomplishing the df$ID condition, and they do. This is the for loop:

```
df
      amountS amountN  ID
64693   0.440    0.55 028
64702   0.360    0.52 028
64708   0.220    0.33 028
64714   0.500    0.27 028
64720   0.280    0.51 028
64726   0.520    0.47 028
64732   0.410    0.25 028
64735   0.090    0.11 028
64741   0.220    0.17 028
64750   0.630    0.48 028
64756   0.430    0.35 028
64762   1.200    0.40 028
65150   4.425   14.95 029
65156   5.035   23.60 029
65163   5.810   26.20 029

idvector <- c("010","025","028")

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
    for (j in seq_len(length(idvector))){
      if(df$ID[i] == idvector[j]){
        print(df$amountN[i])
      }
    }
  }
```

So far, so good. However, I've tried many things to get those values into a vector by changing the function print() in the last line, but nothing seems to work:

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
    for (j in seq_len(length(idvector))){
      if(df$ID[i] == idvector[j]){
        x <- c(df$amountN[i])
      }
      x
    }
  }
```

I also tried to get the subset of df$amounN to then convert the data to vector using `subset` and `select` from `dplyr` library, but also don't get that, instead I get NULL:

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
    for (j in seq_len(length(idvector))){
      if(df$ID[i] == idvector[j]){
        x <- subset(df$amountN[i,])
      }
      x
    }
  }
```

I looked into the data and notice that the values look like this:

```
[1] 0.55
[1] 0.52
[1] 0.33
[1] 0.27
[1] 0.51
[1] 0.47
[1] 0.25
[1] 0.11
[1] 0.17
[1] 0.48
[1] 0.35
[1] 0.4
```

And they should look like this:

```
 [1]  0.55  0.52  0.33  0.27  0.51  0.47  0.25  0.11  0.17  0.48 
[11]  0.35  0.40
```

I really need a vector or a subset so I can apply summary statistics and others to the data, but have not figure it out.

I'm using R version 4.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `base R`, we can do this more easily with `subset`

```
subset(df, ID %in% idvector, select = amountN)$amountN
#[1] 0.55 0.52 0.33 0.27 0.51 0.47 0.25 0.11 0.17 0.48 0.35 0.40
```

---

Regarding the OP's code, we can fix by defining 'x' as a `NULL` vector and then concatenate 'x' within each loop, and assign it back to 'x'.  Also, make sure that the 'idvector' is of the same type i.e. assuming it is numeric as well

```
x <- c()
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
    for (j in seq_len(length(idvector))){
      if(df$ID[i] == idvector[j]){
        x <- c(x, df$amountN[i])
      }
      x
    }
  }
```

-output

```
x
#[1] 0.55 0.52 0.33 0.27 0.51 0.47 0.25 0.11 0.17 0.48 0.35 0.40
```

NOTE: The issue in the OP's code was that 'x' was getting updated on each iteration while removing the previous output.  It needs concatenation

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(amountS = c(0.44, 0.36, 0.22, 0.5, 0.28, 0.52, 
0.41, 0.09, 0.22, 0.63, 0.43, 1.2, 4.425, 5.035, 5.81), amountN = c(0.55, 
0.52, 0.33, 0.27, 0.51, 0.47, 0.25, 0.11, 0.17, 0.48, 0.35, 0.4, 
14.95, 23.6, 26.2), ID = c(28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("64693", 
"64702", "64708", "64714", "64720", "64726", "64732", "64735", 
"64741", "64750", "64756", "64762", "65150", "65156", "65163"
))

idvector <- c(10, 25, 28)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm actually using yours but I'm new here! worked so well

Answer (score 0):

You could directly avoid the loop ans using `%in%` over `df` and indexing:

```
#Code
vec <- df$amountN[df$ID %in% idvector]
```

Output:

```
 [1] 0.55 0.52 0.33 0.27 0.51 0.47 0.25 0.11 0.17 0.48 0.35 0.40
```